# JavaFX MediaPlayer playing background music loop with small intro music

Tags: audio, javafx, media

I am trying to create a game using JavaFX. I had been trying to insert some background musics to the game. The musics are of compatible .mp3 files. I am currently using `MediaPlayer` to playback each `Media`. Each media file consist of the actual loop and a small (optional) intro music to the loop. How can I achieve smooth audio playback using JavaFX.

Methods I have tried:

- Using the `Media` as one file; I try to alter the `mediaPlayer.startTime`, `mediaPlayer.stopTime`. It seems that the duration of the music is shortened when I enter the loop. However, the music restarts at the intro and ends at the wrong place. It was as if `startTime` didn't offset the music at all.
- Using the `Media` as two separate files (intro and loop); I try to immediately playback the loop music as soon as the intro music is finished (using `mediaPlayer.setOnEndOfMedia()`). However, the transition was too slow and noticable.

Comment: Why don't you want to use the event "onEndOfMediaProperty()"? When the song hits the end, you get a notification and can start the next track.

Comment: It was too slow; the skip was very audible. There wasn't an problem with the media itself, I checked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After experience with other well-known game engines (e.g. Unity), I found that the files should be in `.wav` format as opposed to `.mp3` format. This will allow the music to be looped seamlessly.